# Use passthru to make sure the cmdlet is finished

Tags: powershell, iis, powershell-3.0, web-administration

I'm confused how `-Passthru` works.

From my understanding, the `-Passthru` parameter is used for passing the result of a cmdlet to the pipeline even the cmdlet itself doesn't produce any results.

I tried to write these code first: (I'm trying to recycle the IIS Application Pool without using `Restart-WebAppPool` cmdlet)

```
Stop-WebAppPool  -Name Foo
Start-WebAppPool -Name Foo
```

As I expected, it takes time to stop a IIS ApplicationPool, and since PowerShell does not wait for cmdlets to finish their job, the `Stop-WebAppPool` stops the application pool and returns. Because the application pool is not ready to get started, the `Start-WebAppPool` is called and error is thrown.

So I changed my code into these:

```
Stop-WebAppPool  -Name Foo
Start-Sleep -Seconds SomeValueNeedToGetMeasuredAndChanged
Start-WebAppPool -Name Foo
```

It works but not very elegent and flexible.

Then I add `-Passthru` to both of the cmdlets, it becomes:

```
Stop-WebAppPool  -Name Foo -Passthru
Start-WebAppPool -Name Foo -Passthru
```

Everything goes fine and no error is thrown.

In my case, I suppose:

The Stop/Start-WebAppPool cmdlet does not produce any results until the Application Pool really get stopped/started. Since `-Passthru` requires something to pass to the pipeline, PowerShell waits for the cmdlet produces its result, in this case, application pool get stopped/started, to execute the next one.

I can't find any useful manuals on either `-Passthru` or `Stop-WebAppPool`, so is it alright to do so in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`-Passthru` is used to pass current object (i.e. AppPool) further down the pipeline. I don't think that it's guaranteed, that `Start/Stop-WebAppPool` cmdlets will wait for current operation to complete before passing down AppPool object. It works now, but it could break later.

Solution? Use [Restart-WebAppPool](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790580.aspx). Or if you really need to use Start/Stop cmdlets, do it like this:

```
$AppPool = 'Foo'
Stop-WebAppPool -Name $AppPool 
while((Get-WebAppPoolState -Name $AppPool).Value -ne 'Stopped'){
    Start-Sleep 1
}
Start-WebAppPool -Name $AppPool
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I removed `-PassThru` and used codes you provided above! Works like a charm!